# Why my varnish health check always return the backend server is sick?

Tags: varnish

I used varnish as cache server before my nginx web server. I configured the health check for the definition of backend server in varnish configuration file. But the varnish always return my backend server is sick, while I stopped my varnish and directly connected nginx server, it can works well. I try to use .url or .request to enable backend server check, it never work well. Its crarzy how to resovle it.

My configuration is :

```
probe backend_healthcheck {   
.url = "/";
.window = 5;
.threshold = 3;
.interval = 300s;
}

backend nginx2 {
.host = "10.161.78.249";
.port = "80";
.probe = backend_healthcheck;
}

backend nginx2 {
.host = "10.161.78.249";
.port = "80";
.probe = backend_healthcheck;
}

import directors;
import std;
sub vcl_init {
new webserver = directors.hash();
webserver.add_backend(nginx1,1.0);
webserver.add_backend(nginx2,1.0);
}

sub vcl_recv {
set req.backend_hint = webserver.backend(req.http.cookie);
}
```

I really don't know which configuration is error? The varnish is running on the server has public ip and the backend server only has internal ip.

Hope some help me, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the request has to return `200 OK` for Varnish to accept this as healthy.
Could it be that your framework returns `302` on the `/` URL?

Also, your `.window` size means that the servers start as sick and remain sick until you get `.threshold` consecutive healthy responses, which would take 15 minutes in your case.

Also, what does the log show?

Documentation:
https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/BackendPolling

Comment: Thanks a lot, I checked the url of healthcheck. Its really return 302.